# load() not working with javascript included file

Tags: jquery

in my **index.php** i have div#result and javascript code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#result").load("api/api_file.php"); 
}
```

**api_file.php** like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/api.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var api;
....
...
..
api.write("api");

});
</script>

<div id="api" >loading 123456</div>
```

http://mysite.com/api/api_file.php working perfectly but

http://mysite.com/index.php output is **loading 123456**

Comment: what output did you expect exactly? I dont think ajaxed content will get you js generated things. only php.

Comment: @user1721135 required to give graphical output when running api_file.php. ---- api.write ("api"); line is printing graphic when i was running directly http://mysite.com/api/api_file.php

Comment: that wont work. ajax will not get you js generated content.